# Publish cached map service using pre-existing cache folder

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, web-service, cache

We use:
ArcGIS Server Advanced Enterprise 10.3                                                                          / 
                                                                                     ArcGIS Desktop Basic 10.3
both located on a Windows Server 2012 machine

We've received a directory containing a cached map (bundle files). We don't have a mxd file, we don't have the data, just the cache.
This directory is not located on the deafault *C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgiscache,* and we don't intend to move it there, as there woudn't be enough space on disk C:\ . The cache is quite large 280 GB. So I've created a new cache directory in ArcGIS Server Manager that leads to the exact path of our cache.

[image]

We would like to publish this cache as a cached map service/image service on the server. I've added it to ArcMap, but when publishing it as a map service, ArcMap doesn't automatically recognize that it's a cached service. As it is shown in this video: http://video.arcgis.com/watch/964/publishing-cached-map-services-using-a-pre_dash_existing-cache-folder

[image]

It works as a dynamic service

What is this correct procedure to make this existing cache available on ArcGIS Server as a service?

Comment: Is this an existing map service that you're trying to change the cache location for, or is this a new map service?

Comment: it's a new map service I'm trying to publish. It's not a cache created by me, I'm just trying to publish it on the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cache mentioned above was residing in a folder, that was located in another folder, that was located in another folder. So despite the fact that I registered the main folder as a cache folder for the server, it couldn't read inside all these folders.

So we created a new folder, named it exactly as the map service and moved there only the folders containing the bundle files.

The bottom line is to not store your cache in a cascade of folders.