# Publishing Map Service using cache through ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, arcgis-server, map-service, cache

We have a raster mosaic for which we have the cache saved on a network.

How can someone publish this cache as a service without actually creating a tile package?

Here is the cache with Level 12 bundle files, which we need to publish to ArcGIS Server.

I found a post [Publish cached map service using pre-existing cache folder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137631/publish-cached-map-service-using-pre-existing-cache-folder), but not sure about the procedure.

[image]

Comment: Are you loading the mosaic into a map and publishing as a map service or publishing the raster mosaic as an image service?  Typically you should do the latter.

Comment: Hi @bixb0012, No there is no mosaic that we are using as it is missing the raster's. We only have these bundle files as shared above which were created back in time. Which we are trying to use to publish.